# Configure Wicket with HTTPS protocol

Tags: jakarta-ee, https, wicket, wicket-7

I need to configure my project so that it has secure communication with the HTTPS protocol, following the instructions in the Wicket 7 documentation ([Configure HTTPS](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_using_https_protocol)) but I can not make my project work.

The browser shows me the message: "Unable to connect".

I see that in the browser bar if you want to access by https but does not connect.

My system is done in Wicket 7, it is hosted on a server Jboss 7.1.0 Final

Could you help me? I am new with development in JAVA and Wicket.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Wicket documentation doesn't explain how to configure your web container's HTTPS connector. You need to check JBoss' documentation for this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, review the documentation and now my project already works with the HTTPS protocol